# I'm trying to search a pdf for the author and am not allowed to use any of the third party pdf modules available

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to search a pdf for the author and am not allowed to use any of the third party pdf modules available. The code I wrote is below:. What I am trying to do is get the name of the author and thought that using re would allow me to search for the string "Author" and return the name in the field. I am new to Python programming and have not programmed before. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
import re
f=bytes("k://file.pdf",'ascii')
open("k://file.pdf")


for line in f:
    if re.match("(.*)(Author)(.*)", line):
        print (line),
The error message I get is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "K:\hw3pdftest.py", line 8, in <module>
    if re.match("(.*)(Author)(.*)", line):
   File "C:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 160, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

That was what I tried first but got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K:\hw3pdftest.py", line 6, in <module>
    for line in f:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 515: character maps to <undefined>
```

Then I tired to encode it using cp1252 and got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K:\hw3pdftest.py", line 5, in <module>
    f=open("k://file.pdf", "r", "encodings=cp1252")
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Comment: I tried that but got the following error message.

Comment: `f=open("k://file.pdf", "r", encoding="cp1252")`

Comment: You are trying to read a binary file as text so you have use an encoding that allows an arbitrary sequence of any byte values. [CP1252](http://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1252.TXT) has only 251 characters; Try [CP437](http://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/PC/CP437.TXT). But unless you identify which bytes are text and in which encoding, you could mangle the author's name.

Comment: What part of the document do you want to read the author from? From the page content? From meta data?

Answer (score 2):

This is not right:

```
f = bytes("k://file.pdf",'ascii')
for line in f:
    ...
```

You are not iterating lines in pdf, you are iterating the byte values in `b'k://file.pdf'`, that is the ASCII codes of characters `k`, `:`, `/` ..., which are integers. You ought to do:

```
f = open("k://file.pdf")
for line in f:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

PDF stores (according to the [official PDF Specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf)) the author name as the following key in the PDF dictionary:

```
/Author (John Doe)
```

So you should try to run the following regular expression against PDF file

```
\/Author.+\((.+\))
```

It will return the author name as the match #1. Please notice that in some cases you may need to do the additional decoding of this string (in case it uses Unicode symbols which can be encoded the enter code here special way)